# Simulating ajax request with python using the requests lib

Tags: python, json, ajax, python-requests

when i call https://www.shirtinator.de/cT=search/motives&sq=junggesellenabschied
at the upper you get the possiblity to switch to next side and to switch between 50 and 100 motives displayed.

I try to code ,using pythons requests, the post request including the parameter for the ajax script to change between 50 and 100 respectively to change betwenn the side.

I used chromes developer tools to detect the post formsform data of the post request.

This is my script, whicht do not deliver the desired data.

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://www.shirtinator.de/?cT=search/motives&sq=junggesellenabschied"
data1= {"xajax":"searchBrowse","xajaxr":"1455134430801","xajaxargs[]":"1","xajaxargs[]":"true","xajaxargs[]":"true","xajaxargs[]":"motives","xajaxargs[]":"100"}
r = requests.post(url, data=data1)
result = r.text
print result
```

Thanks for the support.

Best

Comment: I don't know what a correct response looks like, but you probably just need to use the `json` parameter instead of the `data` parameter. That yields a longer and more correct looking response.

Comment: The correct response should the the the html ,respectively xml code.
You can see the correct response under chrome --> developer tools --> Network--> select the xhr requst--> response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the same key more than once when creating the dict (data1), the last value will override all previous occurrences.
In your case, what you get is:

```
In [2]: data1= {"xajax":"searchBrowse","xajaxr":"1455134430801","xajaxargs[]":"1","xajaxargs[]":"true","xajaxargs[]":"true","xajaxargs[]":"motives","xajaxargs[]":"100"}

In [3]: data1
Out[3]: {'xajax': 'searchBrowse', 'xajaxargs[]': '100', 'xajaxr': '1455134430801'}
```

As you can see, the xajaxargs[] parameter does not contain all the values it should contain as an array. The correct way to do this in a way that requests will understand is to make the value of xajaxargs[] a list of these values:

```
In [4]: data1= {"xajax":"searchBrowse","xajaxr":"1455134430801","xajaxargs[]":["1", "true", "true", "motives","100"]}
```

Comment: Thanks @noamk, works well so far :) 
Do you also for what the 
`code`"xajaxr":"1455134430801" parameter is responsible ?
Best Bob174

Comment: Looks like a timestamp (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time):

    >>> datetime(1970, 1, 1) + timedelta(milliseconds=1455134430801)
    datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 10, 20, 0, 30, 801000)