# Why can't Python request lib replicate this Ajax call?

Tags: python, ajax, request

**Short version:**
This Python request doesn't work. The Javascript version does. Why?

```
import json
import requests
url = 'https://inputtools.google.com/request?itc=ja-t-i0-handwrit&app=demopage'

data = '{"app_version":0.4,"api_level":"537.36","device":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36","input_type":0,"options":"enable_pre_space","requests":[{"writing_guide":{"writing_area_width":200,"writing_area_height":200},"pre_context":"","max_num_results":1,"max_completions":0,"ink":[[[100,100],[20,180],[0,1]],[[20,180],[100,100],[2,3]]]}]}'

headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}

r = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=headers)
print r.json()
```

**Longer version:**
I have this Javascript that successfully makes an Ajax call. I print the response to the console and can see an array of suggested characters from the input I send.

https://jsbin.com/wufesifasa/1/edit?js,console,output

```
var text = {
  'app_version' : 0.4,
  'api_level' : '537.36',
  'device' : window.navigator.userAgent,
  'input_type' : 0, // ?
  'options' : 'enable_pre_space', // ?
  'requests' : [ {
    'writing_guide' : {
      'writing_area_width' : 200, // canvas width
      'writing_area_height' : 200, // canvas height
    },
    'pre_context' : '', // confirmed preceding chars
    'max_num_results' : 1,
    'max_completions' : 0,
    'ink' : []
  } ]
};

// written coordinates to be sent
text.requests[0].ink = [
  [[100,100],[20,180],[0,1]],
  [[20,180],[100,100],[2,3]],
];

console.log(JSON.stringify(text))

$.ajax({
  url : 'https://inputtools.google.com/request?itc=ja-t-i0-handwrit&app=demopage',
  method : 'POST',
  contentType : 'application/json',
  data : JSON.stringify(text),
  dataType : 'json',
}).done(function(json) {
  console.log(json);
});
```

Output:

> ["SUCCESS", [["fb02254b519a9da2", ["+", "十", "t", "T", "ナ", "f", "子",
>   "干", "1", "千"], [], [object Object] {   is_html_escaped: false }]]]

Now I'm trying to replicate that in Python. I've tried using the above code and many variations of it, but every time I receive the response 'FAILED_TO_PARSE_REQUEST_BODY'. What's different between the Ajax and Python calls that makes my request fail?

This question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35326206/simulating-ajax-request-with-python-using-the-requests-lib) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22183899/simulating-ajax-request-with-python-using-requests-lib), but they deal with using the same key multiple times and incorrect data encoding, which I do not think applies in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `json=data` should have been `data=data`. The json attribute accepts a dictionary, which that `data` string is not. Here is what working code looks like:

```
import json
import requests
url = 'https://inputtools.google.com/request?itc=ja-t-i0-handwrit&app=demopage'

data = '{"app_version":0.4,"api_level":"537.36","device":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36","input_type":0,"options":"enable_pre_space","requests":[{"writing_guide":{"writing_area_width":200,"writing_area_height":200},"pre_context":"","max_num_results":1,"max_completions":0,"ink":[[[100,100],[20,180],[0,1]],[[20,180],[100,100],[2,3]]]}]}'

headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}

r = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=headers)
print r.json()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not enough reputation to comment, but Ray had it correct, though the posted coded still showed 'json=data', instead of 'data=data'.  I ran the code, and got the matching response that OP was looking for, though I just printed r.content

```
`b'["SUCCESS",[["fb02254b519a9da2",["\xe5\x8d\x81","+","t","\xef\xbc\x8b","f","\xe3\x83\x8a","1","\xe3\x83\x88","\xe5\x8d\x9c","\xe5\xa3\xab"],[],{"is_html_escaped":false}]]]'`
```